# How to define Undirected Graph class with Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I need write a function to BFS a Graph, in C++, I can define a Graph struct like this:

```
struct UndirectedGraphNode {
    int label;
    vector<UndirectedGraphNode *> neighbors;
}
```

How should I define it in OC? here is what I do:

```
@interface UndirectedGraphNode:NSObject
@property(noatomic, assign) NSInteger label;
@property(noatomic, copy) NSArray* neighbors;
@end
```

Is that right? How can I avoid retain cycle in this piece of code?

Comment: You don't have a type defined for `label`.  To avoid retain cycles, you need to use something other than `NSArray`.  You're probably better off manually breaking the cycles at need, though.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's a mistake. To avoid retain cycles, do you mean I need use __weak to manually break cycle?

Comment: You can't make the `neighbors` property weak, or you won't ever have any.  You need to use a different container that doesn't keep strong references.  Keep in mind that none of the NS containers (set, dictionary, array) can hold `nil`s, so they can't store weak references.  They can, when bridged to the CF types, hold unretained references.